# Mail not receive from AWS SES

Tags: email, boto3, amazon-ses, google-workspace

I verified my domain (for example: mydomain.com) in AWS SES and configure GSuite to receive emails. Everything ok except when i send mail using SES to admin@mydomain.com.

Here is my test case:

```
From                                To                                  By      Result  
no-reply@mydomain.com               anythingexceptadmin@mydomain.com    AWS     OK  
no-reply@mydomain.com               admin@mydomain.com                  AWS     NG  
anythingexceptadmin@mydomain.com    admin@mydomain.com                  AWS     NG
anythingexceptadmin@mydomain.com    admin@mydomain.com                  Gmail   OK
no-reply@anotherdomain.com          admin@mydomain.com                  AWS     OK
```

Does anybody have an idea how to get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Email address added to suppression list with bounce.